# Truffle test case to unit test withdrawal pattern

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript, unittesting, truffle-test

How can I test the `withdraw()` function in a truffle javascript test case for the below contract?

The problem is, If I use the `msg.sender` from the same contract, the before and after balance will be same.

Is there a way to create a new test contract and use it to call the `withdraw` function from the javascript test case?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import "./ConvertLib.sol";

contract MetaCoin {
    mapping (address => uint) balances;

    event NewDeposit(address _from, uint256 _value);

    function MetaCoin() public {
        balances[tx.origin] = 10000;
    }

    function getBalance(address addr) public view returns(uint) {
        return balances[addr];
    }

    function deposit() payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        NewDeposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function withdraw() {

        if ( ! (msg.sender.call.value(balances[msg.sender])() ) ) {
            throw;
        }

        balances[msg.sender] = 0; // Please don't worry about re-entrancy for now.
    }                   
}
```

[Withdrawal Pattern](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/common-patterns.html#withdrawal-from-contracts)

Comment: Doesn't truffle provide you with multiple wallets (addresses) to work with.

Answer (score 0):

For your test you can crate a DepositorWithdrawer contract able to call deposit/withdraw from MetaCoin. When the DepositorWithdrawer contract is calling MetaCoin, `msg.sender` will be the contract address.

The process would look something like this.

```
MetaCoin mt = new MetaCoin();
DepositorWithdrawer w = new DepositorWithdrawer();
w.transfer(10 ether);
w.deposit(mt);
// do your assert here
w.withdraw(mt);
// do your assert here
```

Personally, I would prefer doing this as a JavaScript Test. There you have better control about who is sending the transaction and you don't have to code unnecessary contracts.

Comment: exactly, still searching for a way to do that in Javascript.